# Upgrading CentOs form 6.6 to 6.7

Tags: centos6

Having an issue upgrading a box from CentOs 6.6 to 6.7.

Running `yum upgrade` does not, however seem to perform as expected in that is does not 'see' nor suggest to update to 6.7. Here is what I have for the following commands:

`cat /etc/centos-release`:

```
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

`yum upgrade`:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, post-transaction-actions, rhnplugin, security
Cleaning repos: centos6-x86_64-updates-66-20150713 centos66-x86_64 epel6-centos6-x86_64 remi remi-safe spacewalk23-client-centos6-x86_64 webtatic
          : zabbix20-centos6-x86_64
```

I am assuming that it is a config issue causing this, but I can't find anything related to this specific issue.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the official CentOS repositories.

Comment: The name of the repos strongly suggests that you're pointing at 6.6 release specific repos, and not tracking the main '6' repo.  You aren't going to get 6.7 if only 6.6 is in the repos in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repo id `centos6-x86_64-updates-66-20150713` sounds like a custom repo that is frozen on 6.6.  You should install the official centos-release package and remove those custom files under `/etc/yum.repos.d`.